# Why SharePoint client object model retrieves all items when query fails?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml, sharepoint-object-model

I'm trying to get the items from a child list (a lookup list i suppose, i'm new in SharePoint development) that are related to their items in the parent list. For brevity, lets call them list A for parent and list B for child. So in general, list   A has at most 4 to 5 child items from list B, and it can sometimes have no item from B at all. I'm using the amazingly useful Camlex.Net library for creating the caml queries. This is the caml that i'm creating via camlex, very basic:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="VisitSummary" LookupId="True" />
      <Value Type="Lookup">1</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

The problem is that when item 1 in list A (like in the xml above) doesn't have items in list B, so SharePoint returns all the items in list B, which is not desirable at all. When list A does have child items in B, it works well, it gets only the related items.
Is there a way to tell SharePoint to return some other value, perhaps null or whatever instead of all the items in the child list?

thanks,
ashilon

Comment: Try to surround the query with `<view>` tag see [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110925/caml-query-returns-all-items-instead-of-one) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675644/sharepoint-use-sp-camlquery-in-jquery)

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I wonder why doesn't Camlex.Net doesn't add it itself. Anyways Max thanks a lot, how do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Below I posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must surrond the query with the `<view>` tag.

See this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675644/sharepoint-use-sp-camlquery-in-jquery) and this on [stackexchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110925/caml-query-returns-all-items-instead-of-one)

Comment: Thanks Max, that was what I needed.